# foo: { $gt: "A", $lt: "Z"}; How do I write this in the scala driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala

```
collection.find({foo: { $gt: "A", $lt: "Z"}});
```

How do I write this in the [Filters](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.6/builders/filters/) DSL in the [MongoDB Scala Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/)?

I know I can write

```
and(gt("foo", "A"), lt("foo", "Z"))
```

but that is the equivalent of

```
collection.find({$and([{foo: {$gt: "A"}}, {foo: {$lt: "Z"}}])});
```

Which seems much less elegant to me.

Comment: You may call it less elegant but that's how it is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver will merge the filter clause values in your case

```scala
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.{BsonDocument, codecs}
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._

object Try extends App {
  var f = and(gt("foo", "A"), lt("foo", "Z"))
  println(f.toBsonDocument(classOf[BsonDocument], codecs.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY))
}

// output
// {"foo": {"$gt": "A", "$lt": "Z"}}
```